# Sweetalert won't show but it will update

Tags: javascript, php, forms, session, sweetalert

I want to show a sweetalert after clicking the set button but it won't function. This is my index page and the set button can function but it won't show the sweet alert. what might be the problem and what should I do?

index.php

```
 <form method='post' action='updataStatus.php'>
                <button type='submit' name='but_update' class="inline-block float ml-2 mt-1 btn-group pull-right btn-danger btn-sm">SET</button><button type="submit" id="dataExport" name="dataExport" value="Export to excel" class="inline-block float ml-2 mt-1 btn-group pull-right btn-info btn-sm">Export</button>
                <div class="table-responsive">

                <br>
                        

            

                  <tbody><table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="sampleTable2">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" id="checkAll" /></th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Scholarship Program</th>
                      <th>Course</th>
                      <th>Semester</th>
                      <th>Allowance</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                   <?php 
                    require_once "connection.php";
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM allowance";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $Name = $row['Name'];
                        $Scholarship = $row['Scholarship'];
                        $Course = $row['Course'];
                        $Semester = $row['Semester'];
                        $statusAllowance = $row['statusAllowance'];
                    ?>
                        <tr>

                            <!-- Checkbox -->
                            <td><input type='checkbox' name='update[]' value='<?= $id ?>' ></td>
                            <td><p name="Name"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></p></td>
                            <td><p name="Scholarship"><?php echo $row['Scholarship'] ?></p></td>
                            <td><p name="Course"><?php echo $row['Course'] ?></p></td>
                            <td><p name="Semester"><?php echo $row['Semester'] ?></p></td>
                            <td><p name='statusAllowance_<?= $id ?>'><?php echo $row['statusAllowance'] ?></td>

                        </tr>
                    <

?php
    
                        }
                        ?>
                      </table>
                    </tbody>

 <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] !='')
      {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          swal({
            title: "<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>",
            icon: "<?php echo $_SESSION['status_code']; ?>",
            button: "yissh",
          });

        </script>

        <?php
          unset($_SESSION['success']);
      }

      ?>
```

This is my code on the edit part and this works, only the alert won't show up.
updataStatus.php

```
 <?php
            require_once "connection.php";

              if(isset($_POST['but_update'])){

                  if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                      foreach($_POST['update'] as $id){
                          $statusAllowance = 'Received';

                                    if($statusAllowance != '' ){
                                        $updateUser = "UPDATE allowance SET statusAllowance='".$statusAllowance."' WHERE id=".$id;
                                        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$updateUser);

                                        if($query_run){
                                          $_SESSION['success'] = "YOUR DATA UPDATED";
                                          header('Location: tracking.php');
                                        }else{
                                          $_SESSION['success'] = "YOUR DATA IS NOT UPDATED";
                                          header('Location: tracking.php');
                                        }

                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                      }

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

considering you have not implemented another function to call sweetalert; by default, it should be `Swal.fire({})` not just `swal({})`

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: well then copy any alert code on sweetalerts website and copy paste on dev tools then hit the enter. If it fires, then more code is needed (like gotta check whether `session_start()` is included or not) but if not, it means that you haven't initialized sweetalert properly(try having cdn script tag inside `<head></head>`)